# Jquery .load() function confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the body of my main html page, I have `<span id="someID">Something to be changed.</span>` I have a script that loads in a tag from another page every second with `$("#someID").load("otherPage.html #IDfromOtherPage");`
On the other html page, the only lines I have are tags for example: 
`<span id="IDfromOtherPage">1</span>
 <span id="AnotherIDfromOtherPage">2</span>`
At the beginning of the script I have an alert that is `alert(document.getElementByID("someID").innerHTML` set for debugging purposes and before the .load, the alert says "Something to be changed.", which is correct. Then it runs the .load, waits a second then runs the function again with the next alert. Every alert after the very first correct one says the entire line from the otherPage.html file. The alert says "`<span id="IDfromOtherPage">1</span>`" instead of just "1". 
Am I doing something wrong? (these id names and file names are just to hopefully make this question easier to follow, not actual variable names)

main html file:

```
<body>
       <span id="someID">Text to change.</span>
 </body> 
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        setInterval(function(){
            alert(document.getElementById("someID").innerHTML);
            $("#someID").load("values.html #IDfromOtherPage");
        }, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

in my other html file
    `<span id="IDfromOtherPage">1</span>
    <span id="AnotherIDfromOtherPage">2</span>`

Comment: Can you post your complete code?

Comment: Just FYI, `alert` is a browser component which expects **string** and displays it. If anything else is passed, it will be converted to string and then displayed. So your markup will be evaluated as string and not as HTML

Comment: @TrevorD i edited with my code

Comment: @Rajesh That's fine. I just want to see what is inside my <span> tag every step. The first time it's right but the second time it isn't what I expect. I seems like the entire line turns to `<span id="someID"><span id="IDfromOtherPage>1</span></span>` because the alert dispays "`<span id="IDfromOtherPage>1</span>`"

Comment: @SteveBabs try `document.getElementById("someID").textContent`

Comment: @Rajesh This is what I needed. I didn't know this was a thing as I'm sort of new to this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation of jQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) (with a fragment #selector) states:

> This element, along with its contents, is inserted

So the `innerHTML` of `#someId` becomes `<span id="IDfromOtherPage">1</span>`, and not just `1` as you seem to be expecting. This explains why the alert shows that full HTML fragment.

To see just `1`, try this:

```
alert(document.getElementById("someID").textContent);
```

This will strip off all HTML and just use the text(s) that are present inside the element.

Comment: Thank you! This worked! I have another side question. I want to check the value inside of a span tag in the other file and then change the span tag of my main file accordingly. Like if the text of the span from the other page equals 1, then change the text on my main page to "Error". So I wouldn't be using the load function, I would be using something else to peek at the value from another page, is there a function for that?

Comment: In that case, use `load()` with an added `complete` function (see the doc link) that contains `if ([.....].textContent == "1") { [.....].textContent = "Error"; }`.